# Loggin con el usuario de Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, login

Estoy desarrollando una ventana de loggin en una aplicación de escritorio en Java 8 y JavaFx, De la **forma clásica** donde a JDBC le paso los parámetros de conexión :

```
          "localhost",
          ":3306",
          "/logginDB",
           usuario,
           pass,
          "?useSSL=false&requireSSL=false"  + "&tcpKeepAlive=true"  + "&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true" + "&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false" + "&serverTimezone=UTC"
```

1) Al inciciar la ventana de loggin, me conecto al servidor (local) para consultar los usuarios y contraseñas y poder comparar.
2)escribo el usuario y la contraseña y comparo la contraseña ingresada con la contraseña almacenada en la tabla usuarios.
3) **Permite o niega el acceso** a la aplicación según sea el caso.

Pero me he dado cuenta que al crear este tipo de ventana, **la contraseña del servidor y usuario root** se tiene que colocar en alguna parte del código Java o en el pool de conexiones.

Entonces he pensado en otra forma de loguearme, y es creando usuarios en la base de datos y conectando a la base directamente mediante cajas de texto,ejemplo:

1)Se abre el panel del loggin pidiendo usuario y contraseña (sin conectar al servidor)
2)Se escribe el usuario creado en la base de datos , ejemplo: carlos.roma@localhost
3)Se escribe la contraseña
4)Si la contraseña de usuario de base es correcta: se abre la conexión.

Notas: El usuario y contraseña no está almacenado en alguna tabla. Y de esta forma no necesito almacenar o cifrar la contraseña del root

Lo que no se si esta última forma es correcta o funcional.

Comment: El detalle que para la conexion necesitas un usario de BD y para el login un usuario de aplicacion, son cosas diferentes, por ejemplo root sera el usario de BD pero no estara en una tabla de usuarios de aplicacion

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Todo esto está pensado para no dejar la contraseña del root o del usuario de base almacenada en alguna clase (Ofuscar no ha funcionado, ya que no ofusca cadenas de conexión). Ya que con un descompilador de Java  sacan el usuario y contraseña fácilmente. En todo caso tendría que cifrar un archivo con los parámetros de la conexión, descifrar ese archivo cuando cargue el panel de login, conectar e iniciar el proceso de login clásico, donde en la base hay una tabla de usuarios y contraseñas.